# Calculating angle of tubes

Tags: geometry

I Am planning on building a parabola, which is connected to a round plate via 3 tubes which have equal length (85cm) and are as far from each other. The round plate has a diameter of 11,6cm and the parabola one of 156,6cm. What angle would the tubes be at compared to fully vertical?

[image]

Thanks

EDIT: UPPER CIRCLE IS 11,6 NOT 16,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diameter of the lower section is $156.6$, giving a radius of $78.3$. The diameter of the upper section is $11.6$ giving a radius of $5.8$.

This can be seen as a right angle triangle. The length from the bottom of a tube to directly below the top, running across the horizontal, is the difference in the radii.
$$78.3-5.8=72.5$$
So that's the length of the horizontal section. You already have your hypotenuse of $85$. You're looking for the angle off of full vertical, so let's find the angle to the top of the tube that goes straight down. this makes the $72.5$ the opposite side, so you use $\sin$.
$$\sin\theta=\frac{72.5}{85}$$
$$\theta\approx58.53^\circ$$

Diagram for clarity:

[image]